# Not getting code coverage if code has 'sortBy' method to sort list items

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit

I am using this method to sort the list of items

```
list.sortBy { item ->

     item.name
}
```

Getting this error when I try to run UT to get code coverage.

```
[2020.08.04 10:05:13] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: com.xxx.method.ABCViewModelTest$$special$$inlined$inject$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.08.04 10:05:13] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: com.xxx.method.ABCViewModelTest$$special$$inlined$sortBy$1: java.lang.Throwable
```

Comment: share your test code

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue with code coverage for `inline` functions

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39038